# Repeated measure for multinomial logistic GLMMs in SPSS?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, multinomial-logit

I am analyzing some linguistic data, where each subject has to rate the acceptability of a number of sentences on a scale of 1-7. I am running a Generalized Linear Mixed Model in SPSS, with a cumulative link.

I wanted to add the "item" variable as a repeated measure, since all subjects see all items, and I see no other way in SPSS to add random intercepts for items as well as subjects, however, SPSS does not seem to support repeated measures for ordinal outcomes. I have been advised to run Generalized Estimating Equations instead, but as far as I am aware, there is no way to add random effects to a GEE, so that is not exactly what I am looking for.

Is there a way to add "item" as a random intercept without specifying it as a repeated measure?

Comment: First, is it SPSS Statistics or Modeler?
Second, what kind of model function are you using?
Third, what do you mean by "item variable"?
Fourth, would you explain a bit more on the case for context?

Comment: By its construction, GEE doesn't have random effects -- it has an assumed correlation structure.  You will simply select the "Repeated" tab under GEE menu and then you'll need to specify a correlation structure.  Why do you say GEE is not exactly what you are looking for if you were advised to use it?  What makes you think it's not appropriate?

Comment: Because I explicitly have to model by subject and by item variability, and as far as I know, that is only possible by specifying them as random intercept. GEE, as you said, does not have random effects. I was only advised to use it as a "surrogate" for an ordinal GLMM with repeated measures.

Comment: I am using SPSS Statistics, version 25. I am using the GENLINMIXED procedure with a multinomial link function, which can be used to fit cumulative link logit models as far as I know. By "item variable" I simply mean the variable in the dataset that encodes which survey item the given observation belongs to. What it boils down to, is that when the multinomial link function is specified, SPSS does not allow a repeated measure variable to be specified in the data structure tab, and explicitly says that it is not possible. I am simply wondering why this is the case, and if there is a workaround.

Comment: You still include random effects, but you don't model them explicitly in GEE as you do with mixed models.  You treat the random effects as a nuisance parameter in terms of the correlation structure.  I would recommend you read through the SPSS help documentation and example on how GEE works.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/tutorials/gee_wheeze_intro.html

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful information indeed, I will check it out and report back what I managed to do with my data.